# Haskell: use of unsafePerformIO for global constant bindings

Tags: haskell

There are lots of discussions of using `unsafePerformIO` carefully for global mutable variables, and some language additions to support it (e.g. [`Data.Global`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/global-variables-1.0.1.1/docs/Data-Global.html)). I have a related but distinct question: using it for global *constant* bindings. Here’s a usage I consider entirely OK: command-line parsing.

```
module Main where

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import Data.Bool (bool)
import Data.Monoid ((<>))
import Options.Applicative (short, help, execParser, info, helper, fullDesc,
                            progDesc, long, switch)
import System.IO.Unsafe (unsafePerformIO)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
data CommandLine = CommandLine
  Bool               --quiet
  Bool               --verbose
  Bool               --force

commandLineParser = CommandLine

  <$> switch
    (  long "quiet"
    <> short 'q'
    <> help "Show only error messages.")

  <*> switch
    (  long "verbose"
    <> short 'v'
    <> help "Show lots of detail.")

  <*> switch
    (  long "force"
    <> short 'f'
    <> help "Do stuff anyway.")

{- Parse the command line, and bind related values globally for
convenience. This use of unsafePerformIO is OK since the action has no
side effects and it's idempotent. -}

CommandLine cQuiet cVerbose cForce 

  = unsafePerformIO . execParser $ info (helper <*> commandLineParser)
      ( fullDesc
     <> progDesc "example program"
      )

-- Print a message:
say     = say' $ not cQuiet -- unless --quiet
verbose = say' cVerbose     -- if --verbose
say'    = bool (const $ return ()) putStrLn

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
main :: IO ()

main = do
  verbose "a verbose message"
  say "a regular message"
```

It is very valuable to be able to refer `cQuiet`, `cVerbose`, etc. globally rather than have to pass them around as arguments wherever they’re needed. After all, this is exactly what global identifiers are for: these have a single value that never changes during any run of the program — it just happens that the value is initialized from the outside world rather than declared in the program text.

It makes sense in principal to do the same thing with other sorts of constant data fetched from the outside, e.g. settings from a configuration file — but then an extra point arises: the action which fetches those is not idempotent, unlike reading the command line (I’m slightly abusing the term “idempotent” here, but trust that I’m understood). This just adds the constraint that the action must be performed only once. My question is: what’s the best way to do that with code of this form:

```
data Config = Foo String | Bar (Maybe String) | Baz Int

readConfig :: IO Config
readConfig = do …

Config foo bar baz = unsafePerformIO readConfig
```

The [doc](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/System-IO-Unsafe.html) suggests to me that this is sufficient and none of the precautions mentioned there are needed, but I’m not sure. I’ve seen proposals for adding a top-level syntax inspired by do-notation specifically for such situations:

```
Config foo bar baz <- readConfig
```

… which seems like a very good idea; I’d rather be sure the action will be performed at most once than rely on various compiler settings and hope no compiler behavior comes along that breaks existing code.

I feel the fact that these are in fact constants, together with the ugliness involved in passing such things around explicitly despite the fact that they never change, argue strongly for there being a safe and supported way to do this. I’m open to hearing contrary opinions if someone thinks I’m missing an important point here, though.

**Updates**

- The `say` and `verbose` uses in the example are not the best, because it’s not values in the `IO` monad that are the real annoyance — these could easily read the parameters from a global `IORef`. The problem is the use of such parameters pervasively in pure code, which have to all be rewritten to either take the parameters explicitly (even though these do not change and thus should not need to be function parameters), or be converted to `IO` which is even worse. I’ll improve the example when I have time.
- Another way to think about this: the class of behaviors I’m talking about could be obtained in the following clunky way: run a program that fetches some data via I/O; take the results and substitute them into the template text of the main program as the values of some global bindings; then compile and run the resulting main program. You would then safely have the advantage of referring to those constants easily throughout the program. It seems that it should not be so hard to implement this pattern directly. I phrased the question mentioning `unsafePerformIO`, but really I’m interested in understanding this kind of behavior, and what the best way to obtain it would be. `unsafePerformIO` is one way, but it has drawbacks.

*known limitations:*

- With `unsafePerformIO`, when the data-fetching action happens is not fixed. This may be a feature, so that e.g. an error related to a missing configuration parameter occurs if and only if that parameter is ever actually used. If you need different behavior, you’ll have to force the values with `seq` as needed.

Comment: Everything about the design of Haskell is supposed to discourage the use of globals this way -- and for good reason; globals cause code not to be compositional and encourage subtle coupling, two sources of subtle bugs that can be tricky to track down. I would think twice and maybe thrice before using `unsafePerformIO` over `ReaderT`.

Comment: Thanks, but I don’t see how your comment relates to my question; I think you’re oversimplifying. Global mutable state is problematic and discouraged in favor of other mechanisms. This is not global mutable state; it is global constants whose values are initialized from the outside world and thereafter do not change. There are many applications of `unsafePerformIO` that range from entirely innocuous to wholly unsuitable; I think this occupies a middle ground that is worth discussing (more interesting is whether this is a usage that should be supported in some more direct and safe way).

Comment: Another way to think about this: the class of behaviors I’m talking about could be obtained in the following clunky way: run a program that fetches some data via I/O; take the results and substitute them into the template text of the main program, as the values of some global bindings; then compile and run the main program. You would then safely have the advantage of referring to those constants easily throughout the program. It seems that it should not be so hard to implement this pattern directly.

Comment: The difference being, of course, that the distinction between parts of the program that rely on configuration information -- hence may be coupled to other actions that also rely on the configuration -- and the parts that are independent of configuration is no longer transparently available by their types. This additionally makes reasoning about program behavior more difficult; because one may no longer rely on the sanctity of types and must therefore *always* inspect the implementation to discover whether the configuration is consulted or not.

Comment: That’s an interesting point: people use types to track different kinds of information. Absent `unsafePerformIO` and friends you can use types to tell you about what the program could possibly depend on, in a broader sense encompassing the whole system in which the program runs. With it, even if the use is sound in terms of language semantics, the types now say less about that.

Comment: Constants that very between different program runs aren't really constants. Such global pseudo-constants do perhaps not cause quite as much trouble as global variables that vary _during_ runtime, but still quite too much trouble. I can tell a story of this from experience with Fortran hydrodynamics simulation code... the global configuration parameters are a maintenance nightmare. Please, do just pass the configuration around as an explicit parameter... this really isn't so ugly, not in modern Haskell with lenses etc..

Comment: ...That said – I still think such constants could have good uses: for data that actually is constant even between program runs, but too big to hard-code. Hence, +1.

Comment: I usually feel such global constants *should* be function parameters; the behavior of the function *is* parameterized by the "constants" and I *do* need call the functions with different values of these "parameters" (when the program is invoked with different arguments/config). Making them actual parameters makes it easier to test, easier to generalise the program so that something it previously only did once per run it now does several times, easier to factor things into a library.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I'd consider top-level command line parsing to always be OK! Specifically, observe what happens with this alternate `main` when the user provides bad input.

```
main = do
  putStrLn "Arbitrary program initialization"
  verbose "a verbose message"
  say "a regular message"
  putStrLn "Clean shutdown"
```

> ```
> > ./commands -x
> Arbitrary program initialization
> Invalid option `-x'
>
> Usage: ...
> ```

Now in this case you can force one (or all!) of the pure values so that the parser is known to have run by a well-defined point in time.

```
main = do
  () <- return $ cQuiet `seq` cVerbose `seq` cForce `seq` ()
  -- ...
```

> ```
> > ./commands -x
> Invalid option `-x'
> ...
> ```

But what happens if you have something like—

```
forkIO (withArgs newArgs action)
```

The only sensible thing to do is `{-# NOINLINE cQuiet #-}` and friends, so some of those precautions in `System.IO.Unsafe` do apply to you. But this is an interesting case to patch over, note that you have given up the ability to run sub-computations with alternate values. An e.g. `ReaderT` solution using `local` doesn't have that drawback.

This seems an even larger drawback to me in the case of reading config files, as long running applications usually are reconfigurable without requiring a stop/start cycle. A top-level pure value precludes reconfiguration.

But maybe this is even more clear if you consider the intersection of both your config files and your command line arguments. In many utilities arguments on the command line override values provided in a config file, an impossible behavior given what you have now.

For toys, sure, go hog wild. For anything else, at least make your top-level value an `IORef` or `MVar`. There are some ways to still make the non-`unsafePerformIO` solutions nicer though. Consider—

```
data Config = Config { say     :: String -> IO ()
                     , verbose :: String -> IO ()
                     }

mkSay :: Bool -> String -> IO ()
mkSay quiet s | quiet     = return ()
              | otherwise = putStrLn s

-- In some action...
  let config = Config (mkSay quietFlag) (mkVerbose verboseFlag)

compute :: Config -> IO Value
compute config = do
  -- ...
  verbose config "Debugging info"
  -- ...
```

This also respects the spirit of Haskell function signatures, in that it's now clear (without even needing to consider the open world of IO) that your functions' behavior actually does depend on program configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I’m aware of these limitations, but I wouldn’t go so far as to say that the technique demonstrated in the sample program is only for “toys.” As far as timing goes (your “Arbitrary program initialization”), this is in fact often the behavior I want. It is useful to not have to decide up front in which program mode I need a particular external parameter, but rather let laziness abort the program if and only if it actually gets used. Of course, sometimes the initialization is expensive and so I’d force it as you describe in order to find out.

Comment: Similarly, for a reconfigurable daemon I would never use this technique in the first place, because then the configuration is not in fact constant; it’s changing data read from the outside world and should be handled as usual using monadic I/O. I want to limit the discussion here to constants read from the outside. Your point about command-line/configuration overriding is well taken, though; I do that often but just hadn’t gotten to it yet in these programs. It’s possible that there are just too many caveats to make this attractive when taken all together; that’s exactly what I’d like to see.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, I don’t see that overriding is really a problem. If there’s a top-level parameter foo :: Foo specified in configuration that may be given on the command line, then I’d have confFoo :: Foo for the former and cmdFoo :: Maybe Foo for the latter, and compute foo = fromMaybe confFoo cmdFoo. This is better anyway in that I don’t then lose track of the provenance of the setting.

Answer (score 1):

[-XImplicitParams](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#implicit-parameters) is useful in this situation.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ImplicitParams #-}

data CommandLine = CommandLine
  Bool               --quiet
  Bool               --verbose
  Bool               --force

say' :: Bool -> String -> IO ()
say' = bool (const $ return ()) putStrLn

say, verbose :: (?cmdLine :: CommandLine) => String -> IO ()
say = case ?cmdLine of CommandLine cQuiet _ _ -> say' $ not cQuiet
verbose = case ?cmdLine of CommandLine _ cVerbose _ -> say' cVerbose
```

Anything that is implicitly typed and uses `say` or `verbose` will have the `?cmdLine :: CommandLine` implicit parameter added to its type.

```
:type (\s -> say (show s))
(\s -> say (show s))
  :: (Show a, ?cmdLine::CommandLine) => a -> IO ()
```

Comment: Also note [this trick](https://kcsongor.github.io/global-implicit-parameters/) which lets you use them globally - extremely useful to avoid a major refactor.

Answer (score 0):

Two cases from Hackage that come to mind:

The package [**cmdargs**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cmdargs) makes use of `unsafePerformIO` - treating command line arguments as constant.

In the package [**oeis**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/oeis), the
"pure" function [`getSequenceByID`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/oeis-0.3.6/docs/Math-OEIS.html#v:getSequenceByID) uses unsafePerformIO to return content from a web page on http://oeis.org. It notes in its documentation:

> Note that the result is not in the IO monad, even though the implementation requires looking up information via the Internet. There are no side effects to speak of, and from a practical point of view the function is referentially transparent (OEIS A-numbers could change in theory, but it's extremely unlikely).